# Controlling memory consumption by memoized function

Tags: performance-tuning, memory, memoization

To speed up a resource-intensive calculation, I use several functions with storing previously calculated values. For example:

```
a2N[k_?IntegerQ, bv_?NumericQ, p_?NumericQ] := 
  a2N[k, bv, p] = 
   NIntegrate[Re@a2sub2[bv, p (1 - \[Psi]^k)], {\[Psi], 0, 1}
    , Method -> "LocalAdaptive"
    , AccuracyGoal -> 10];
```

Each of these memoizing functions can be called multiple times with the same set of arguments when calculating the coefficients of the differential equation, but accumulate millions of `DownValues`, as happens in long loops over the `k` parameter and a few others that enter through argument `bv`, I do not see the point due to the nature of the loop.

My laptop has 16 GB of memory, but this was sometimes not enough, which led to an unexpected abortion of the program. On a desktop with 32 GB, abortions also happened, but rarely. On a desktop with 64 GB, the situation is even better. Armed with these observations, I began to control memory consumption.

First of all, I discovered that Matematica itself is able to free some memory from time to time. And it does this the better, the more physical memory available to the computer. But still, I decided to help her. When available memory dropped below a certain limit, I first tried to remove `DownValues` like this:

```
clearCache[f_] := 
  DownValues[f] = 
   DeleteCases[DownValues[f], _?(FreeQ[First[#], Pattern] &)];
funcs = {a2N, a2D1N, a2D2N, bva2N, bva2D1N, bva2D2N, P1N, P1D1N, A1N, 
  A1D1N, B1N, B1D1N};
clearCache[#]&/@funcs//ParallelEvaluate
```

It was a couple of weeks ago. Maybe I did something wrong, but I did not notice a positive effect. I suspect that I measured `MemoryInUse[]` on the main kernel, but not the parallel subkernels. Therefore, I decided to kill the kernels forcibly, and then restart them again:

```
memTitles = {"PhysicalTotal", "PhysicalUsed", "PhysicalFree", 
   "MemoryAvailable"};

If[SystemInformation["Machine", "MemoryAvailable"] < 
   1/10 SystemInformation["Machine", "PhysicalTotal"] ||
  SystemInformation["Machine", "PhysicalFree"] < 
   Quantity[1 + $KernelCount/2, "Gibibytes"]
 ,
 Speak["Подозреваю нехватку памяти. Будет выполнен перезапуск \
ядер."];
 Print["Подозрение на нехватку памяти. Будет выполнен перезапуск \
ядер."];
 Print[mem1 = ParallelEvaluate[{$KernelID, MemoryInUse[]}]];
 CloseKernels[]; LaunchKernels[];
 Print[mem2 = ParallelEvaluate[{$KernelID, MemoryInUse[]}]];
 Print["Было высвобождено ", 
  Plus @@ ((mem1[[All, 2]] - mem2[[All, 2]])/1024^3 // N), " GiB"];
 AppendTo[
  memoryA, {{subStep - 1, k, q, Mm, Rm}, 
   SystemInformation["Machine", #] & /@ memTitles, 
   DateDifference[DateObject[], startDate0, "Hour"]}];
 ]
```

In fact, this is exactly what Matematica did itself in most cases when it saw a lack of memory. The figure below shows a typical graph that my `healtReport` module prints from time to time:

[image]
[image]

The first figure shows the control plot before forced shutdown of the subkernels. The second graph shows the final graph after the completion of the full calculation cycle.

My question is related to the green graph. It shows how `PhysicalFree` changes over time. The surprise is that Mathematica continued to work without failures for at least two hours at all with zero `PhysicalFree`. I have observed this phenomenon several times. **How can this even be?** And the main question: **Which type of memory out of the four listed is best to control?**

**Update 2022-10-26:**

In the next calculation, I first removed `DownValues` [Number of stored `DownValues`: 37808272 in 12 functions in 8 kernels]. This freed up 6.27418 GiB. Restarting the kernels freed up another 38.4929 GiB. I don’t understand where else the memory is leaking, although I seem to have read all the posts on this topic on this site.

Comment: Memoizing for a function with real-valued inputs seems wasteful and a bit wild, especially in dimension $>1$. Can you not construct interpolation functions instead of memoizing?

Comment: @user293787: I used interpolation for coefficients of ODE composed of the function listed in my post. Some coefficients can be singular and therefore interpolated ODE sometime gives unsatisfactory results. The most reliable results are obtained when interpolation is not used.